# Encoding characters to utf-8 hex in Python 3

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have a web crawler that get a lot of these errors:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe1' in position 27: ordinal not in range(128)
```

To mitigate these errors I have implemented a function that encode them like this:

```
def properEncode(url):
    url = url.replace("ø", "%C3%B8")
    url = url.replace("å", "%C3%A5")
    url = url.replace("æ", "%C3%A6")
    url = url.replace("é", "%c3%a9")
    url = url.replace("Ø", "%C3%98")
    url = url.replace("Å", "%C3%A5")
    url = url.replace("Æ", "%C3%85")
    url = url.replace("í", "%C3%AD")
    return url
```

These are based on this table: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

The conversion I do seems to be to convert them to utf-8 hex? Is there a python function to do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *URL encoding* them. You can do so trivially with the `urllib.parse.quote()` function:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote
>>> quote("ø")
'%C3%B8'
```

or put into a function to only fix the URL path of a given URL (as this encoding doesn't apply to the host portion, for example):

```
from urllib.parse import quote, urlparse

def properEncode(url):
    parts = urlparse(url)
    path = quote(parts.path)
    return parts._replace(path=path).geturl()
```

This limits the encoding to just the path portion of the URL. If you need to encode the *query string*, use the `quote_plus` function as query parameters replace spaces with a plus instead of `%20` (and handle the `query` portion of the URL).